# Group parallel (similar) polylines together

Tags: math, polyline

How can I check if two polylines are close to parallel? They don't have to be exacly parallel, but should be similar in the sense that they are going in the same direction

@Edit

I think I need to explain a bit more the idea behind everything. As a input I get many poly-lines. What I want to do is group the polylines together that are quite parallel (in general similiar orientation). The result will be groups of similar poly-lines.

How do the poly-lines look like. They in general go straight upwards or to the left or right side. The don't have to start at the same y-value. The points of the polylines are in general not at the same height, that means have different y-value. As often the polylines are parallel in some interval and then start to differ I would like to find interval borders and define parts of the polyline parallel in this interval. Of course the interval should not be to small

I will now illustrate an example and what results I would like to have. Starting with 4 polylines, P1 to P4 shown in blue. For a human it is obvious that the lines P1-P3 are quite parallel until the red line b1. Therefore this sould be the first group G1 of parallel polylines. After the redline b1 there are the parallel polylines P1 and P4. Therefore they build group G2. The poly-line P3 is not parallel to anything else and therefore is alone in group G3.
Hope that illustration helps
[image: General Picture]

Example of two poly-lines that should be declared as parallel:

[image: Example of two poly-lines that should be declared as parallel].

Example of two poly-lines that should be declared as **NOT** parallel

[image: Example of two poly-lines that should be declared as NOT parallel]

@Edit 2
After applying the douglas peuker algorithm to the input polylines I get this result. Now I want to group parallel polylines together. How do I find the corresponding lines segements that I want to compare?
Also as you see in figure "How to compare the segments" that the polylines 1 and 2 should only be grouped together in the interval [b1,b2]. How do I find this interval?
That actually means I need to find which segments to compare. If I compare them and if they are not parallel I classify as not parallel. If they are parallel I still need to find the interval in which they are parallel, right? That's because one polyline can start and end bevor another one.
[image: How to compare the segments]

Comment: "They don't have to be exacly parallel, but should be similar in the sense that they are going in the same direction." What about segments that go in the same direction but intersect eachother?

Comment: Have they always general direction (bottom to up or another) and could be considered as single-valued function X(y)?

Comment: Yes, it is always a single-valued function. As shown in the two examples, if you plot x from left to right and y from bottom to top to every y exists one x.

There is not always a general direction. I mean the poly-line could also be a curve.

Comment: If selected direction does exist, you can think about calculation of correlation (coefficient)

Answer (score 1):

First reject any intersections.

Then do a linear regression on the lines. Establish a threshold for "roughly parallel". Now choose one polyline and take the most distant point from the line of best fit (if it is an end chose the next point). Now split the other polyline at the point of "best fit" (basically distance with a bit of slop to allow little local deviations and to cut on a corner point if possible).

Repeat until none of the line segments are polylines, and apply a fairly generous distance and direction threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Malcolm,
Actually my poly-lines can be parallel and still intersect. If the red poly-line would be shiftet by 2.5 to the right. They are still parallel, but would intersect multiple times.

I didn't get the algorithm you explained. Could you give it another try?

Comment: The idea is that if you do a least squares fit to both poly lines, you get straight lines which will certainly not be parallel, but might be reasonably parallel. Then divide and conquer by splitting one of the lines at the worst point of fit, and splitting the other at the "most parallel" point. Do that repeatedly until you just have straight line segments.

Comment: So it goes in the direction of the Douglas-Peuker algorithm. I actually implemented your idea and the Peuker Algorithm. The results are quite similar. What I get is a Polyline that is represented by a few linear lines. The problem is now how I can compare them of being parallel.  Of course I need to find a fairly generous distance and direction threshold. But my problem is that I don't know which line segments I need to compare. How can I find out which segments I need to compare?

Comment: Another problem is that if two have parallel segment of different length. If i compare them of orientation they are the same. But actually they could just overlap in some part. How do I get that part?

Answer (score 1):

For each vertex on polyline A, find the closest point on polyline B and output the distance between these two points. (Using the closest vertex instead may work just fine.)
Do the same for B with respect to A.

Now do a linear regression on the distances found. You should get a horizontal line, approximately. Define a threshold for this check.

Comment: Thanks Ihf,
That's a nice idea. I will try that out. Do you have any idea how I find the red border b1, until which two poly-lines are parallel, bevor they start to differ?

My first idea is to look at the distances. If the distance is smaller or bigger then the regression line thats no sign for divergence. But if the distance starts to grow/decrease from step to step that would be a sign that they are no longer parallel, right?

Answer (score 1):

in your example you know the each of pairs of line segments share y-axis coordinates so those are indexes, 
Also the lines are continuous per your example.

the distance between the two lines at each endpoint (y coordinate) is known. so:

```
for y in 0:n
   delta_x[y] = abs(blue_x[y] - red_x[y])
```

then if you subtract the smallest delta_x[y] from all of them
you will have a non-negative curve, the area under this curve
will be proportional to how parallel your lines are

less area more parallel,
more area less parallel,
perfectly parallel no area.

But only you could choose your threshold.

Comment: w.r.t OPs @edit and the new wavy line graphic,  they are still polylines and they do still have end points and the for every existing endpoint on one line there is either an endpoint or an interpolatable point on the other line.  Your set of Y values becomes the union of the set of y values given in either line computing the x value if lookup fails. (where computing is linear interpolation from the closest endpoints on the line)

Comment: I thought about something similiar. I agree that it's a good metric vor evaluating the similarity of two polylines. But not for what I personally would classify as parallel. ( Of course this classification can be seen in a different way) I classify two poly-lines as parallel if there orientation is about the same. The problem with the area is that I could have the same are for two cases. The one case ist that they are about the same as shown in figure "Example .... declared as parallel:" The other case would two lines that start parallel, but one of them drifts a way in a monotone way.

Comment: @Contine....
That means that in every step the distance between the curves is getting larger. That is for me less parallel than  in the other case, because it has a complete different orientation.
The are does not tell anything about that behaviour. But exactly that is what I want. Am I right about that? Or do I miss something?

Comment: true, the area us just a bound on how parallel they could be.

Comment: if you are below some value for area you know you could not be diverging significantly, to accept as parallel lines with a greater area, looking at the derivative(s) of the curve we are integrating could help, either the average derivative from all points along the curve or the derivative of the linear regression of the curve (or a combination) would give additional sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do if look at the problem in the dual space. You may have come across the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) which is used in image processing. This maps lines to point, and the set of points is called the dual space.

The basic idea is that you can parametrize a straight line y = m x + c, by the pair of numbers (m,c). You could do this for each segment in each polyline. These give a set of points for each segment. These points should form two clusters centred around (m1,c1) and (m2,c2). For the lines to be parallel then you would have m1 = m2.

This would require some form of clustering algorithm, possibly k-means, so you probably need some for computer vision toolkit. To parametrize the lines you probably don't want to use (m,c) as these don't work for vertical lines. Some algorithms use the angle of the line and the distance from a point.

A refinement on this is to try and fit line segments to parts of the polyline. You could start by defining a length for the line segment and then find subsets of the polylines with approximately this length.
With these subsets then do some line fitting, say linear regression. With these fitted lines you can then use the dual parameters, to compare the fitted lines.

---

If we think about lines and points in dual space there is a relationship

```
normal space   <--->   dual space

line           <--->       point
point          <--->       line
```

So every line corresponds to a point and every point corresponds to a line.

If we map the polyline to dual space we might get something like

[image: dual space for polyline]

This is not an acurate diagram. Each line segment becomes a point and each point becomes a line. What you would find is the dual space would kind of wrap around the dual space representative of the fitted line.

Comment: I think Hough transform is a nice idea. I still have some problems with it.
1) If both clusters are the same that still doesn't mean they are parallel, because clusters are not ordered. That means a line with orientation m1 and them m2 has the same cluster as a line with orientation m2 and m1. But they are not parallel, right?
2) Even if they would have the same order, they could have different length. That means if one polyline is a scaled version of the other, they still have the same cluster.
Am I right? But hough transform still sounds good, because orientation is an important point.

Comment: But I am still struggling with an approach based on hough transformation. Are there any ordered clusters?

Comment: This is really finding a statistical interpretation of parallel. An m1, followed by m2  will have an average gradient (m1+m2)/2 the same as m2 followed by m1. You could think of these as statistically parallel, just one with a kink to the left and one with a kink to the right. 

Scalling should not affect the gradients but it might affect the intercepts. It would probably represent shift in the (m,c) space.

You might be able to weight points by segment length.

Comment: Yes, the interpretation of parallel is important. In my case the same average gradient should not necessarily mean parallel. In the aboved mention case of m1, m2 they should be declared as non parallel, if m1 and m2 differ a lot. Scaling does not change the gradient. Exactly this is the problem, as it seems that two lines are similar. But actually the scaled version can be completely different. I think weighting is a first step in the right direction. But then I still have the problem that the ordering of the orientations has to be the same if they start/end at the same y position.

Comment: If the polylines have different length, then the ordering of gradients can also differ. The main problem is that I have to know which segments and therefore gradients I have to compare. As for example the segment 1 of polyline 1 can be parallel to segement 2 of polyline 2. So I need to compare these 2 segments. But the important question is how do I know which segments I have to compare. It's not possible to use only y-coordinates, because if both polylines are curves then the parallel parts are shifted in y-direction.